# How to stop event bubbling in this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bpopup

```
$('#div1').on('click', '#otherDiv1', function(event){       
        //Show popup
        $('#popupDiv').bPopup({
            modalClose: false,
            follow: [false, false],
            closeClass: 'close'
        });             
        event.stopPropagation();

        $('#div2').on('click', '#otherDiv2', function (event) { 

             // here is ajax request         

            // close popup          
            $('#popupDiv').bPopup().close();
            event.stopPropagation();
        });

    }
```

Click on otherDiv2 calls ajax function many times, how can I stop this?

HTML code

```
<div id="div2">

<div id="div1"><div id="otherDiv1">Click</div></div>

    <div id="popupDiv"><div class="close">X</div> 
        <input id="otherDiv2" name="otherDiv2" type="submit" value="Click" />   
    </div>
</div>
```

popupDiv is created dynamically

When I click on otherDviv1 the popup is open, inside is a button for ajax request. When I click button a request is called and popup closed. If I click one more time otherDiv1 and button a request is called two times and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Post some `HTML` related to above code

Comment: Do you really want to add a NEW event manager on every click of `#div1` to `#div2` or do you just want to USE the event on div2 within a context of the former click?

Comment: Since you are using event delegation, you really have to post your HTML and exactly explain the behaviour you see. Preventing event propagation has to be done differently with event delegation.

Comment: Mark, I want to use event on div2 within a context of former click I think. The same popup is related and with other former clicks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its not necessary to bind a second `click` within another `click`. Your code bind `click` to `#otherDiv2` on each `click` to `#otherDiv1`. For following process don't need `stopPropagation()`.

```
$('#div1').on('click', '#otherDiv1', function(event) {
    //Show popup
    $('#popupDiv').bPopup({
        modalClose: false,
        follow: [false, false],
        closeClass: 'close'
    });
});

$('#div2').on('click', '#otherDiv2', function(event) {

    // here is ajax request         
    // close popup          
    $('#popupDiv').bPopup().close();
});
```

But If you need to bind event within another event then first unbind the event from `#otherDiv2` and then bind again.

```
$('#div1').on('click', '#otherDiv1', function(event) {
    //Show popup
    $('#popupDiv').bPopup({
        modalClose: false,
        follow: [false, false],
        closeClass: 'close'
    });

    $('#div2').off('click').on('click', '#otherDiv2', function(event) {

      // here is ajax request         
      // close popup          
      $('#popupDiv').bPopup().close();
   });
});
```

Comment: First click and second click should be related, I use the same popup for other events too and it has a different behaviour.

Comment: @uhura no, you don't need that.. binding event like above way will accomplish your job..

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I didn't explain good enough. On first click I take ID which I use in ajax request. Because the function is inside, I can use a local variable.

Comment: I added off('click') in my code like you suggested and it worked (left one click event inside other). But somehow it does't feel a right way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation()
```

to stop the bubbling.

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/

Comment: He does not bind the event handlers to the same element, so why should it help?

Answer (score 0):

If you use quite a fresh version of jQuery, every ajax request returns [Deferred](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) object which you can store in outer scope of click handler and analyse in order to cancel existing request or just not start new one.

Also there is a concept called throttling, and there are [plugins](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) for jquery which does for you.